# Skanda Purana in sanskrit

Tags: scripture, puranas, skanda-purana

I am trying to find pdf of Skanda Purana in sanskrit. Is complete unabridged sanskrit Skanda Purana online or in PDF format? Please provide it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complete [**Skanda Purana**](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D) in sanskrit neatly divided in Khandas and in seprate chapters is avaliable on **Wikisource** website. We also can copy-paste Shlokas from the site. We can also download kandas in PDF format using the blue download button present at right hand side of the page.

Apart from skanda Purana , links to all other puranas in sanskrit are  also avaliable on the same page in the right side box including Valmiki Ramayana.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are different versions of Skanda Purana. Generally it is divided into either Khandas or Samhitas. Khandas are from the North Indian (Nepali) version and Samhitas are found in South India. The version you will find on the internet is only one version out of at least 4.

Here is a link to Shankara Samhita from South India -

- https://archive.org/details/SriSkandaPuranam-SankaraSamhitaPart1
- https://archive.org/details/SriSkandaPuranam-SankaraSamhitaPart2

Different version of Kedar Khand:

- https://archive.org/details/B.1306SkandaPuranaKedarKhandaManuscriptsByIAMVISIONARYTUNES

It is very difficult to find the other north Indian versions or samhitas online.